# ¿qué significa esta syntax?

Tags: javascript

Vengo intentando saber si es un método o una variable junto a una función, pero no logro entender ni encontrar nada, el javascript es:

```
    var auto = {
    nombre: "Mustang",
    anio: 1965,
    motor: 5.5,
    color: "azul",
    clasico: true,
    es_real: false
  }


  function recorrer_objeto(automovil) {
    console.log(this.nombre);
    console.log(this.anio);
    console.log(this.motor);
    console.log(this.color);
    console.log(this.clasico);
    console.log(this.es_real);
  }
  auto.mostrarAuto = recorrer_objeto; // no entiendo esta línea
  auto.mostrarAuto();
```

¿mostrartodo sería una variable de auto o un método? y luego ¿funcionaría mostrrartodo y daría la función sin necesariamente encadenarlo a auto?

Answer (score 4):

> **Deberías considerar leer lo que escribes antes de publicar una pregunta.**

---

En resumen:

Creaste un objeto `auto` inicializando con sus propiedades, luego creaste una **función** llamada `recorrer_objeto` que sirve para obtener y mostrar por `console` las propiedades del objeto a la cual estará enlazada.

Además, al objeto `auto` le estás definiendo un **método** llamado `mostrarAuto` asignándolo con la función llamada `recorrer_objeto`.

> Un método es una función asociada a un objeto, o, simplemente, un método es una propiedad de un objeto que es una función.

```js
var auto = {
 nombre: "Mustang",
 anio: 1965
}

function recorrer_objeto() {
 console.log(this.nombre);
 console.log(this.anio);
  
 console.log(this.propiedadX);
  console.log(this.propiedadY);
}

console.log('Auto:');

auto.mostrarAuto = recorrer_objeto;
auto.mostrarAuto();

var auto2 = {
 propiedadX: "Mustang",
 propiedadY: 1965
}

console.log('Auto2:');
auto2.mostrarAuto = recorrer_objeto;
auto2.mostrarAuto();
```

---

**Referencia:**

- [Trabajando con objectos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos)

Comment: oo entonces es un metodo al cual se le asigno la funcion, gracias a este metodo se vincula auto con la funcion verrdad? ya que nunca se utilizo recorrer_objeto(auto); por ejemplo

Comment: Si te das cuenta en la función `recorrer_objeto(automovil)`, estás enviando el parámetro `automovil` que en ningún momento lo utilizas. Ahora por la vinculación, es "correcto tu comentario".

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente tienes un objeto, el cual sirve para guardar información, pero está mas orientado a ser como una representación de los objetos reales, a qué me refiero? Me refiero a que envés de representar, cualquier información sin cosas en común, en un objeto la información es más relacionada, por ejemplo, en un objeto llamado `auto`, le colocarás la marca, el color, etc.

La función lo que hace es acceder a las propiedades de los objetos, propiedades es del tipo: `key: value` , en donde `key` es el nombre de la propiedad y `value` es su valor, como `nombre: 'Eduardo'`, para acceder a las propiedades es mediante el DOT operator, osea el punto `.`, p.e(por ejemplo)

```
miObjeto.propiedad
```

Luego al final, creas una nueva propiedad al objeto, y le **ASIGNAS** una función, cuando se la **ASIGNAS**, sin los parentesis, es porqué quieres que esa propiedad sea igual a esa función, **pero sin necesariamente ejecutarla**.

Por último ejecutas la función.

*PD: En vez de haber creado una nueva propiedad al objeto, al final, podrías haber hecho eso, en el mismo objeto:*

```
var Obj = {
 copiarFuncion: recorrer_objeto
};
```

```js
var Obj = {
 nombre: 'Eduardo',
 apellido: 'Campos'
};

function _mostrar (){
 console.log("Su nombre es: " + Obj.nombre, Obj.apellido);
}

Obj.muestrame = _mostrar;
Obj.muestrame();
```

Answer (score -1):

Esta parte del codigo :

```
 var auto = {
    nombre: "Mustang",
    anio: 1965,
    motor: 5.5,
    color: "azul",
    clasico: true,
    es_real: false
  }
```

estan solo un objeto en JavaScript

esta parte del codigo estan solo una funcion que recibe el parametro automovil que tan solo esta referiendose a que la funcion recibira un valor que este caso es el valor que tiene el objeto, por ejemplo como vez en el primer console con el

```
this
```

estas indicando(referencia) al valor/propiedad anio del objeto auto y con automovil estas haciendo referencia a ese valor.

```
function recorrer_objeto(automovil) {
    console.log(this.nombre);
    console.log(this.anio);
    console.log(this.motor);
    console.log(this.color);
    console.log(this.clasico);
    console.log(this.es_real);
  }
```

Esta parte la entiendo  pero mi pregunta es : ¿ es todo el codigo o esta incompleto?

```
  **auto.mostrarAuto = recorrer_objeto;**
  auto.mostrarAuto();
```

Pero espero que allas entendido el codigo con mi explicacion.

Comment: loa ctualize con todo el codigo de practica, pero cuando se define automovil en auto ? nunca se puso recorrer_objeto(auto);. esta parte lo define auto.mostrarAuto = recorrer_objeto;? y mostrarauto a que hace referencia ? a otra variable en auto como por ejemplo anio o nombre ?

Comment: sera porque agregastes las ** en mostrarAuto asi nunca en auto.mostrarAuto(); funcionaria en el codigo que publicastes.

Comment: me refierro cuando se vincula el objeto auto con la funcion ya que nunca se uso recorrer_objeto(auto)